# Laravel: One to Many to Many, retrieve distinct() values

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Laravel 4 Project, using Eloquent ORM.

I have three tables: customers, orders and products (+ 1 pivot table order_product). Customers are linked one-to-many to Orders. Orders are linked many-to-many to Products.

```
Customers  1-->N  Orders  N<-->N   Products
```

I would like to have a method on Customer model that retrieves a list of products that customer is buying.

To better understand this, assume products are consumable.

For example Customer #1 can place:

- Order #1 for Products A, B and C;
- Order #2 for Products A, C and D;
- Order #3 for Products C and E;

...and the result I want to retrieve is a Collection with Products A, B, C, D and E.

Models are (pseudo-coded on the fly):

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Order');
    }

}

class Orders extends Eloquent {

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'customer_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }

}

class Customers extends Eloquent {

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Orders', 'customer_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        // What to put here ???
    }

}
```

Comment: You might be able to use hasManyThrough and target the (usually-implicit) pivot table. Something like `return $this->masManyThrough('Order', 'OrderProduct')->with('Product');` But if that doesn't work you'll have to do a bit of manual work in that method and return a query. It won't be too hard (just build a query the way you would without the convenience of a relationship) but it won't be as pretty as a standard relationship.

Comment: @alexrussell : Do I need to create a model for the pivot table for that? Also, my kung-fu with Eloquent low-level query system is not so strong, could you point out the actual code (as an answer, maybe) ?

Comment: yes I think you'd need to model the pivot table in order to use my `->hasManyThrough()->with()` method, otherwise Laravel doesn't know how to relate the pivot table (which is what you're left with after the `hasManyThrough`) to the `products` table (which is a 'hasMany` of the pivot table). As for the other way 9as it's likely the `hasManyThrough` method won't work, I'll see what I can come up with for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @deczo's answer, I was able to put up a single query method to retrieve items:

```
public function items()
{
    $query = DB::table('items')->select('items.*')
        ->join('item_order', 'item_order.component_id', '=', 'items.id')
        ->leftJoin('orders', 'item_order.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
        ->leftJoin('customers', 'customers.id' , '=', 'orders.customer_id')
        ->where('customers.id', $this->id)
        ->distinct()
        ->orderBy('items.id');

    $eloquent = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder( $query );
    $eloquent->setModel( new Item );
    return $eloquent->get();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a Many-to-Many relationship, but with the **Orders** table as the pivot table.

```
class Customers extends Eloquent {

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Orders', 'customer_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Products', 'orders', 'customer_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

I've included the last two parameters, but if you follow the singular_id pattern they can be left out.

It's possible to receive distinct Product models like this:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Products', 'orders', 'customer_id', 'product_id')
        ->distinct();
}
```

Comment: That is *brilliant*. Thanks :-)

Comment: This is the correct way since this is the eloquent way.

Answer (score 2):

@deczo's answer probably works fine, and is probably a lot more performant as all the data reduction is done in the database itself, but here's a 'pure Laravel' way that's undoubtedly more readable:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    ...
    public function products()
    {
        $products = new Collection;
        foreach ($this->orders as $order) {
            $products = $products->merge($order->products);
        }

        return $products;
    }
}
```

Note that this method will not act like normal relationship methods - to get the resulting collection you call the method (i.e. `$products = $customer->products();`) and you can't access it as a property like you can with relationships (i.e. you can't do `$products = $customer->products;`).

Also, I'm kinda going on my understanding of the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection#merge()` method here that it automatically does a `DISTINCT`-like thing. If not, you'll have to do a `$collection->unique()` kinda thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I'm doing right now and it's good to have a confirmation. As far as I understand, the main problem is the performance (I think it generates N + 1 queries). The merge actually return a unique (but unsorted) Collection, that can be easily sorted with a SortBy('id').

Comment: Yeah exactly - not performant but is easier to read code, so it kinda depends on the size of your data and whether or not you can take the performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of easy relation method for this one, but here's a workaround:

```
$productsIds = DB::table('customers')
    ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->join('order_item', 'order_item.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->leftJoin('items', 'order_item.item_id' , '=', 'items.id')
    ->distinct()
    ->get(['items.id']);

$productsIds = array_fetch($productsIds, 'id');

$productsCollection = Product::whereIn('id', $productsIds);
```

Comment: Thanks @deczo, I'm going to give it a try. And it also helped me to better understand how the DB object works :-)

Comment: I think it just misses a ->where('customers.id', $this->id). BTW, is there a better method to get a collection directly from DB object ? If I understand correctly, this makes two queries and after the first I already have everything I need.

Comment: Yes, for a given user you need to append where statement just like you mention. About Eloquent collection - from DB query builder you don't get Eloquent result (Model/Collection of Models), so only way to do it in a single query is to use Product model from the beginning. Try to find that query and let me know if you need any help

Comment: It seems I found a way to do it in one query :-)

Comment: Then you should share it

Comment: There you go, added as answer.