# Laravel relationship distinct

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following foreach, Accessing the **relationship** `approved_applicants`. Where i am checking the number of `array objects`.

**The current condition is giving me two buttons because `DB` have to two `records` where i want to restrict it to one.**

```
@foreach($candidate->approved_applicants() as $vote)
    @if(count($candidate->approved_applicants) >= 2 || $vote->type == 'm')
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled="">Approved</button>
    @else
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Approve</button>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**Controller method :**

```
$pendingRequests = \App\Applicant::with('approved_applicants')->where('company_name',auth()
->user()->company_name)->get();
```

**Relationship :**

```
public function approved_applicants(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ApprovedApplicant');
}
```

I was using the `distinct()` method on relationship but it didn't worked.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It will work:

```
$pendingRequests = \App\Applicant::with(['approved_applicants' => function($query) {
$query->groupBy('user_id');
}])->where('company_name',auth()
->user()->company_name)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
$pendingRequests = \App\Applicant::with('approved_applicants')->where('company_name',auth()
->user()->company_name)->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

For more details [please see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940091/laravel-one-to-many-to-many-retrieve-distinct-values).

Comment: Error : `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'approved_applicants.applicant_id' in 'group statement'`

Comment: @Comrade 'approved_applicants.applicant_id' means your foreign key of applicant table in approved_applicants table

Comment: @Comrade : And i put approved_applicants just for example

Comment: My bad... Still not working `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'applicant_id' in 'group statement'`

Comment: @Comrade Please display your both table structure

Comment: Table `approved_applicants` columns : `id`,`user_id`,`applicant_id`.

Applicants table have nothing of concern, `applicant_id` of `approved_applicants` table have reference of `applicants` table's `id`

Comment: Same problem ! Bro

Comment: @Comrade Can we try with fluent query ?

Comment: @Comrade This is Eloquent query

Comment: it should be this way cause there is alot of work beside then this one with the same query !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
$pendingRequests = \App\Applicant::with(['approved_applicants' => function($q) {
$q->groupBy('user_id');
}])->where('company_name',auth()
->user()->company_name)->get();
```