# I want to get all the user tagged posts. How to ignore if the post of same id repeated?

Tags: php, laravel

I have these 5 tables `Users`, `Tags`, `Posts`, `UserTag`, `PostTag`. I want to retrieve all the tagged post of users . I am getting all the post by

**In controller**

```
$tags = Auth::user()->tags;
```

passing to the view.

**In view.**

```
@foreach($tags as $tag)
  @foreach($tag->posts as $post)
    {{$post->title}}...
    ....
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And than i realize by doing this, I am getting repeated post. while creating the post, the user add multiple tags, and which is all followed by the authenticated user. for example, what i want to do is.

1. `user1` added the `post1` by following `test1`, `test2` tags.
2. the next `user2` has followed `test1` and `test2` tags, he will see all the post which he had tagged.
3. But if `user1` had single post with two tag in point 1, than obviously while getting the post by tags, the one who followed both the tag (`test1`, `test2`) will get repeated post i.e `post1`.

**how to ignore the repeated post? I hope what i am concerned is clear?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: One to Many to Many, retrieve distinct() values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940091/laravel-one-to-many-to-many-retrieve-distinct-values)

Answer (score 0):

You could store a list of IDs that are already displayed and check against these IDs in the loop. If the ID is in the array then `@continue` to the next one otherwise display and store the ID. [You can read more on loops in Laravel in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops)

I would try to move this logic out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using different methods.

## whereHas relation

Retrieving posts with a `whereHas` relation instead of first retrieving the tags will result in you only having to loop through one single unique array.

```php
$posts = Posts::whereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->whereIn('id', Auth::user()->tags->pluck('id')->toArray());
});
```

Now you are only selecting the actual posts without receiving the unnecessary tags first.

You can read about querying relationships in the [Laravel documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

## "Through"-relations

Laravel also provides a convenient (yeah) way to query this by defining an additional relationship of the type *has many through*.

```php
/**
 * Get all of the tagged posts for this user
 */
public function taggedPosts()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\Tag');
}
```

You must define this in the User model (probably User.php).

Now you can simply loop through `Auth::user()->taggedPosts`, e.g.

```php
@foreach (Auth::user()->taggedPosts as $post)
{{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
```

Read more in the [Laravel documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)